# Routing inernal network

Tags: networking, routing, subnet, windows-sbs

I know this is not the ideal or close to ideal network setup, but I have just setup a SBS 2008 server on a KVM/VPS and have encountered a networking issue. I know that the i will lose server feature functionality by not setting up the server the way this OS was intended, but just for testing purposes I want to get this server as close to a productions server as possible to test scripts, patches, new software updates etc.. I have a default gateway on a different subnet then the static IP i was provided by my hosting. And the way that SBS 2008 wants the network to be is you must have a Private Ip address (192.168.1.x) and the default gateway within the same subnet. But since my default gateway provided by my hosting is a 198.27.x.x SBS does not allow me to finish the server configuration wizard. And here comes the question: Is there some kind of software that can help with internal routing? or somewhere along those lines. If needed I can probably add a second network adapter that way one is for internal and has a private IP address and the 2nd adapter would reach out to the internet?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

http://prntscr.com/8ogcoj DHCP provided by hosting

Comment: This isn't specific to SBS. All host must have a local Default Gateway. It's not possible to use a router on a different network as a Default Gateway.

Comment: DHCP server from host assigns a default gateway outside of the subnet. http://prntscr.com/8ogcoj

Answer (score -2):

I've never had to do this before, but it seems possible.

I think you can add the default gateway, if you configure a route to its subnet first.

*Update

Routing to a separate subnet works just fine:

```
route add -net 10.2.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.125
```

So I see no reason why 0.0.0.0 can't be routed the same way. But I checked and it doesn't work, in Linux anyways.

```
route add default gw 10.1.1.1
SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable
```

Comment: By definition a Default Gateway is the local gateway to remote networks... remote being any other network. A network is either local (the network that a particular host is on) or remote (a network that is not the local network). A Default Gateway cannot be on a remote network. You can use a router on another network to get to specific other remote networks, but you cannot use a router on another network as your Default Gateway.

Comment: I only said it seems possible. If you can route to a gateway, and ping it (which works), I believe you should be able to route all other traffic through it. Just because it is not implemented, doesn't mean it is impossible.

Comment: It's perfectly possible to add remote networks to your routing table, as you've stated. The key is that the route to those remote networks must go through your local Default Gateway. It isn't possible to configure your Default Gateway as a router on a remote network. Your host needs to send all traffic destined for remote networks to it's Default Gateway, which must be local to your host.

Comment: In my example above, 192.168.1.125 is on the local subnet. It is not my default gateway, yet I am able to use it to route a subnet. Seems like anything you want to route through needs to be on your subnet. Seems like routers could do more, I don't get the limitation.

Comment: Right. I get what you're saying. You can use another local router (or routers) to route traffic to other remote networks, and that's not uncommon. My entire point is that by definition, a Default Gateway is the router that all traffic destined for remote networks goes to when there isn't a more specific local route to those remote networks and that a Default Gateway must be local to the host using it as a Default Gateway.